# Entity Framework code first migrations with multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with `Owin.Security` authentication. As you know visual studio creates a class inheriting `IdentityDbContext` for handling my application's user database. Besides that I needed to read/write some data from another database so I created another `dbContext` using code first model and worked with it for a while and everything was fine.

Today I needed to make a modification to `IdentityDbContext` so I made some changes in the class files and added some new tables. The problem is that now when I call add-migration in package manager console a migration is created with empty Up and Down methods. I think the problem is with my application having multiple dbcontexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone faces the same problem in the future, what finally solved my problem was excluding old files in *Migrations* folder from my project and call `Enable-migrations -Force -ContextTypeName MySampleContext` with *MySampleContext* being the context that I want to add migrations for. In case I need my old migrations in the future I still have the files and I can include them in my project again.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use `-Context` param for Add-Migration command

```
Add-Migration [-Name] <String> [-OutputDir <String>] [-Context <String>] [-Project <String>] [-StartupProject <String>] [-Environment <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get an error in package manager saying "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'context'"

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. For .net (not Core) you can use `-ConnectionString` param and pass your connection string

Comment: Nope, I'm still getting empty Up and Down methods.